# Sort-Object with unexpected results from Get-Variable

Tags: sorting, powershell

please look up

```
Get-Variable | Sort-Object -property Value
```

at your PowerShell prompt. You'll likely see that the values are all but sorted. There is kind of sorting, some blocks appear to have been sorted, but in between there are - at least in my PowerShell (V4) many items located at completely absurd positions.

Can anyone shed a light on why the `Sort-Object` fails in this case?

Thx

Armin.

Comment: What would you consider not failing? Those variables have values of wildly differing (incomparable) types. Perhaps you expected them to be sorted by the order they would have had if they were all converted to strings first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order between two objects of different types is not defined (unless explicitely defined). Thus, when you try to sort objects, you can’t really expect them to follow what you believe makes sense, or even any real logic.

If you convert them to a common type, e.g. by converting them to a string first, you will get a proper order:

```
Get-Variable | sort { [string] $_.Value }
```

Comment: Shorter: `sort { [string] $_.Value }`; casting can handle nulls.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I swear I was doing that earlier and it failed for me.. but it works now, thanks! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the sample ... I have understood where my thinking error was, expecting a string sort when the default output of objects is not a string. Your sample corrects this, bit if you try it and look closely, that some values are still magled, e.g. PSDefaultParameterValues, PSBoundParameters, and args, they obviously all resolve to empty arrays {}, but in the output they are not sorted together, Isn't this kind of inconsitent behaviour?

Comment: @Armin That’s because the representation shown in the output is not the same as the string value. For many object types, `ToString` will just yield the type name.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it has a hard time sorting the results of this as you would expect is because the values all have different data types. Even though what you are seeing is string values, each of these values has a specific data type such as string, integer, boolean and lots more. There is no consistent set of rules that will sort all of these values correctly. If you do the same with the variable names rather than with the values, you'll see a consistent sort - this is because the variable names are essentially string values and can easily be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, this is perfectly the explanation I was looking for.